# Vue CLI 3 + Vuetify - Not working on IE 11 (Babel does not transpile?)

Tags: babeljs, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3, babel-polyfill

I’m using Vue CLI 3 with Vuetify for my project. It works well on Chrome and iOS 12, but it shows blank page on IE11 and iOS Safari < 12. The console in IE11 shows: `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'`

I think it’s because Babel does not transpile the ES6 syntax (arrow function, spread, etc) to ES5 syntax. I still see it in the compiled code after running yarn build.

Here is my babel.config.js:

```
//bable.config.js
module.exports = {
presets: [
  [ '@vue/app', {
     useBuiltIns: 'entry'
  }]
 ]
}
```

Here is my `.browserslistrc`:

```
//.browserslistrc
> 1%
last 2 versions
not ie <= 8
```

`main.js` is something like this:

```
// main.js
import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/store'
import { firebaseListener } from './firebaseConfig'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

Please help me!
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Change `useBuiltIns`'s value from `entry` to `usage` and remove `import '@babel/polyfill'` from `main.js`

Answer (score 2):

babel.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
     presets: [['@vue/app', { useBuiltIns: 'entry' }]],
  }
```

main.js

```
import '@babel/polyfill' // At the top of the file, and make sure @babel/polyfill is installed
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).